# Custom shortcodes has <pre> and <code> before the returned string

Tags: shortcode

so I have a question regarding custom shortcodes! I created a shortcode for a href as the following:

```
function makeUrl( $atts , $content = null ) {
extract(shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'href' => '#',
    ), $atts ));
return '<a href="'.$href.'">'.$content.'</a>';
}

add_shortcode('url', 'makeUrl');
```

So basic usage is at [url href="http://www.google.com"]Google[/url] however the problem is when it comes to formatting, when I checked the generated code is enclosed in pre and code blocks like the following:

```
<pre class="language-php">
    <code class="language-php">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </code>
</pre>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I tested your shortcode on my clean wordpress install and it works fine. I'm seeing a clean Google link when i put the shortcode in the content wordpress block.  Perhaps you might be using a theme that is conflicting with your code.  Try dropping the shortcode in the default wordpress theme and see if you get the same results.  If you do, then it might be one of the plugins you have installed.

Comment: yeah it seems like it is conflicting with the theme/plugin. Thanks so much